# C# date compare function producing wrong result

Tags: c#, sql-server, webforms

I have two columns `DueDat` and `PaymentDate` of a `datagridview`. I want that
if payment has made either `before` or `ON` or `after`  due date the result should be `Paid`. I need following result while the when comparing both date columns

Today's date is 10-10-2018

```
InstallmentNo    DueDate    PaymentDate    Status
-------------------------------------------------    
1              08-11-2018   18-11-2018      Paid
2              08-12-2018                   Up Coming
3              08-12-2018                   Up Coming
4              08-12-2018                   Up Coming
```

or

```
InstallmentNo    DueDate    PaymentDate    Status
---------------------------------------------------        
    1            27-10-2018               Up Coming
    2            08-12-2018               Up Coming
    3            08-12-2018               Up Coming
    4            08-12-2018               Up Coming
```

but my code produces the following result:

```
InstallmentNo    DueDate    PaymentDate    Status
-------------------------------------------------      
1              08-11-2018   18-11-2018      Paid
2              08-12-2018                   Pending
3              08-12-2018                   Up Coming
4              08-12-2018                   Up Coming
```

or

```
InstallmentNo    DueDate    PaymentDate    Status
--------------------------------------------------        
    1            27-10-2018               Pending
    2            08-12-2018               Pending
    3            08-12-2018               Pending
    4            08-12-2018               Pending
```

Here is my my code which takes input from a `textbox` for the above table data

```
private void txtSID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int isid;
        string sid = "";

        sid = txtSID.Text.ToString();

        if (int.TryParse(sid, out isid)) ;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
        {
            string CmdString = " SELECT InsttNo,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DD,105) as DD,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),PD,105) as PD from InstallmentPaymentHistory where SalesInvoiceID=" + isid + "";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, conn);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("SalesInvoice");
            sda.Fill(dt1);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt1.DefaultView;

            DateTime d1 = new DateTime();
            DateTime d2 = new DateTime();
            DateTime d3 = new DateTime(2011, 2, 19);

            d3 = DateTime.Now;
            string s = d3.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
            {
                var dueDate = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["DueDate"].Value != null
                    ? dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["DueDate"].Value.ToString()
                    : string.Empty;

                var paymentDate = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["PaymentDate"].Value != null
                    ? dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["PaymentDate"].Value.ToString()
                    : string.Empty;

                if (!DateTime.TryParse(dueDate, out d1) || !DateTime.TryParse(paymentDate, out d2)) ;

                int a = DateTime.Compare(d1, d2);

                int b = DateTime.Compare(d3, d1);

                if ((a <= 0 || a >= 0) && paymentDate.ToString() != "")
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Status"].Value = "Paid";
                else if (b <= 0)
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Status"].Value = "Up Coming";
                else
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Status"].Value = "Pending";
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exp.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: DateTime.Compare(, ); function is producing wrong result

Comment: `if (int.TryParse(sid, out isid)) ;` you do realise you could ignore the result 
 and just do `int.TryParse(sid, out isid)`

Comment: check values of d1, d2, d3 in debugger.

Comment: `a <= 0 || a >= 0` will always be true

Comment: Please read up on [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Comment: @TGnat not much chance of SQL injection in this case as the input is not passed directly in to SQL but parsed first

Comment: @ Markus Dresch Value of d2 is  "1/1/0001 12:00:00 Am"  for table # 1 while value for d1 and d2 for table # 2 is "1/1/0001 12:00:00 Am"

Comment: @shakeelahmad a value of 01/01/0001 is the default for DateTime and suggests that the strings could not be parsed. You don't actually do anything if the parsing fails.

Comment: what are the types of `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["DueDate"].Value` and `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["PaymentDate"].Value`? Are they `DateTime`s by any chance?

Comment: More importantly what are the values of `dueDate` and `paymentDate`?

Comment: @phuzi values of dueDate and paymentDate are Ok . Parising is not ok, and value of d2 after parsing is "1/1/0001 12:00:00 Am"

Comment: What does "Ok" mean? Are they the correct DateTime values? If they are, why do you convert to string and parse? Could you tell us the actual values?

Comment: @phuzi  values are as shown in Table # 1 i.e for row# 1 DueDate=08-11-2018   and PaymentDate=18-11-2018

Comment: if i dont parse then their values are "1/1/0001 12:00:00 Am"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181622/discussion-between-shakeel-ahmad-and-phuzi).

Comment: **Typo** alert: it's a **column** - not a "coloum" ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I'm in the UK and parsing a string in the format "dd-MM-yyyy" works as expected with `DateTime.Parse()` and `DateTime.TryParse()`. It probably won't work in other cultures.*

There appears to be a problem with your date parsing you should probably use `DateTime.TryParseExact()` to minimise issues with culture variations.

You should also avoid using `DateTime.Compare()` too, it's just confusing the issue.

```
var dueDateString = "08-11-2018";
var paymentDateString = "18-11-2018";

DateTime dueDate;
DateTime paymentDate;

DateTime.TryParseExact(
    dueDateString,
    "dd-MM-yyyy",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal,
    out dueDate);

DateTime.TryParseExact(
    paymentDateString,
    "dd-MM-yyyy",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal,
    out paymentDate);

if (paymentDate != default(DateTime)) // valid payment date
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Status"].Value = "Paid";
else if (dueDate > DateTime.Today) // due date is in the future
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Status"].Value = "Up Coming";
else // payment is overdue
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Status"].Value = "Pending";
```